# seleccionar un indice de un select en html y en base a ello afectar a otro elemento Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Hola tengo tiempo buscando una respuesta a esto,lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione una opcion de mi select pueda cambiar el texto de un imput

    
        
    
    
        
            
                Solicita:

Direccion General
                    Subdireccion Academica
                    Subdireccion de Servicios Administrativos
                    Subdireccion de Planeacion y Vinculacion

```
                   <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 100px;margin-top: 10px;">Nombre del o la responsable de la informacion: </p>
                   <input id="respo" style="margin-bottom: 5px;margin-left: 40px;width: 400px;" name="responsable" type="text" aria-disabled="true" placeholder=""><br>
                   <input style="margin-left: 150px;height: 40px;width: 200px;margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit" value="Enviar">
               </div>
           </div>
        </form>
    </div>
         </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Por favor trata de añadir un ejemplo de lo que sería tu select con el código minimo necesario para que podamos probarlo y dar solución a tu necesidad. También te pediría que seas un poco más explicito con "opcion de mi select pueda cambiar el texto de un imput" cual input? que deseas que muestre ese input luego de seleccionada la opción?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que al momento de seleccionar una opcion de mi select el valor de mi input se modifique por el valor del select que haya seleccionado
<select>
 <option value="Opcion 1">Opcion 1</option>
 <option value="Opcion 2">Opcion 2</option>
 <option value="Opcion 3">Opcion 3</option>
 <option value="Opcion 4">Opcion 4</option>
 
</select>



<input type ="text" value="">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si creo que he entendido tu pregunta, tienes que hacer saltar un trigger via jquery:

```
var nuevoValor = "El valor que quieras que tome el input text al hacer el change";
$.('#miSelect').change(function(){
    $('#miInput').val(nuevoValor);
});
```

Si el valor que quieres cambiar va en relación con el texto del option del select podría hacerse así:

```
$.('#miSelect').change(function(){
    $('#miInput').val($(this).text());
});
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ha funcionado perfectamente